# Como puedo validar que solo entre numeros

Tags: java, poo

Este es mi código. Sólo me funciona una vez para validar; si ingreso un dato tipo `String`, cuando vuelvo a ingresar un string da error.

```
public class BienvenidaSegundo {

    static String nombre;
    static int caso;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean repetir = true;
        while (repetir) {
            try {
                caso = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la manera quiere imprimir la bienvenida(1-scanner,2-Panel)"));
                validar();
                repetir = false;
            } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadena ingresada, debe ingresar un valor numerico", "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                caso = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la manera quiere imprimir la bienvenida(1-scanner,2-Panel)"));

            }

        }
    }

    private static void operacionPanel() {
        nombre = "";
        while (nombre.equals("")) {
            nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Nombre");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido " + nombre, "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private static void operacionScanner() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre1 = "";
        while (nombre1.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre");
            nombre1 = entrada.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Bienvenido " + nombre1);

    }

    private static void validar() {
        while (caso < 1 || caso > 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero valido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            caso = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la manera quiere imprimir la bienvenida(1-scanner,2-Panel)"));
        }
        switch (caso) {
            case 1:
                operacionScanner();
                break;
            case 2:
                operacionPanel();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

El error que arroja es:

> ```
> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "h"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
> at bienvenidasegundo.BienvenidaSegundo.main(BienvenidaSegundo.java:21)
> C:\Users\Hitler\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)
> ```

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "h"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at bienvenidasegundo.BienvenidaSegundo.main(BienvenidaSegundo.java:21)
C:\Users\Hitler\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: me funciona la validacion solo una vez, pero si vuelvo a ingresar un string me da ese error

Comment: Por favor, toda información que quieras añádir, ponla editando la pregunta (puedes hacerlo cuantas veces quieras). El espacio de las respuestas es sólo para nuestros intentos de respuesta. :) Esta vez te ayudé con el trace del error.

Comment: soy nuevo con la pagina, aun no le entiendo jeje

Comment: No hay problema, acá estamos para ayudar. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes. PD. Estoy probando tu código para ver si te puedo ayudar

Comment: okay amigo, gracias, estaré atento a las respuestas. Haré el recorrido mientras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `main` de tu clase estás repitiendo una instrucción innecesaria para tu ciclo. 
Ese segundo `caso` está dentro del catch y, a su vez, no está rodeado por ningún try-catch que atrape la excepción, por lo que simplemente falla.

Si comentas|eliminas el último `caso`, el ciclo se encarga de volver a mostrar el mensaje pidiendo la opción para procesar el nombre.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean repetir = true;
        while (repetir) {
            try {
                caso = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la manera quiere imprimir la bienvenida(1-scanner,2-Panel)"));
                validar();
                repetir = false;
            } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadena ingresada, debe ingresar un valor numerico", "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
//                caso = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la manera quiere imprimir la bienvenida(1-scanner,2-Panel)"));

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh vaya, era eso.Gracias amigo!!Eres genial.

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudar. Si esta era la respuesta a tu pregunta, márcala como aceptada, así los demás sabrán que resolviste tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo bro, gracias.